# SHA1: different results for PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, sha1

I have a code to generate hash in C#:

```
string hash = GetHash("Ю-41241624.05.1991");

public static string GetHash(string str)
{
    Encoding eu = Encoding.UTF8;
    byte[] data = eu.GetBytes(str);
    SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    return Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(data)); 
}
```

The result is:

```
G7xY+gb35Lw4HlDnTZP89FU3Khk=
```

And I try to get the same result in PHP:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding("Ю-41241624.05.1991","UTF-8");
$hash = sha1($str,true);       
$base64 = base64_encode($hash);  
echo $base64;
```

But the result is:

```
Dg+x7F8lsC/r9O8PNskgJ/MwNgU=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of mb_convert_encoding(), if the string is already UTF-8 it will mess things up.
When I run the code without that function I get the correct result: https://eval.in/620412

Comment: My problem was that I try to run PHP script from Windows console and pass "str" from console. That's why I get wrong hash.
When I write the string inside the script it shows right result.

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is in "**YU**" character. Your c# code looks fine. When you debug the code only with this character, you will get byte array with values **208 174** which is really **Ю** character in UTF8. So c# code should works fine and sha1 from c# should be good.

Can you get byte numbers from php only for char Ю? It should be also **208** and **174**.
If you remove this character your hash string should be equal.